# How do I make Firefox interpret my location as a non-FQDN subdomain on my local network?

Tags: firefox, intranet

How do I make Firefox interpret my location as a non-qualified domain name properly when I type in a non-FQDN without dots?

For example, if I type "foo/home", I want to go to "http://foo/home", not to "https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=foo%2Fhome&ia=web".  But I can't find any such setting.

Comment: Try this Firefox plugin, you can configure redirects - https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/redirector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In about:config, set `browser.fixup.dns_first_for_single_words` to true.

(From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1342299)